# Is it possible to delete a cookie token from database table if the user manually alters cookie value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named **logincookies** in my database and in that table a user’s id is stored against a token. When a user logs in and checks **Remember Me**, a random 134 character string is generated and that string is stored as cookie value.

The cookie value on user’s browser is checked against database value every time a user interacts on the website. If at any time a user decides to alter their cookie value on their browser, the cookies are unset and the user’s log becomes invalid, however, the cookie token is still stored in the db. Is there anyway to delete that entry as well?

If it’s not possible, should I worry about this in terms of unnecessary entries in the table?

I have tried unsetting the cookies if there is a mismatch, but that only unsets it on the browser. I cannot figure out about the server part.

EDIT: This is the code snippet in header.php and header.php is required on every page.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["cookie"])) {

$token = $_COOKIE["cookie"];
//check if the token is valid
if (cookieToken($con, $token) !== FALSE) {
    $user_id = cookieToken($con, $token);
    $user_id = $user_id["user_id"];         
    $user_credentials = cookieUserDummy($con, $user_id);
    $email = $user_credentials["email"];
    $pwd = $user_credentials["pass"];
    cookieUserLogin($con, $email);
    } else {
        unset($_COOKIE['cookie']); 
        setcookie('cookie', '', time() - 3600, '/');
        echo "Cookie Session Expired. Log in Again<hr>";
    } 
}else {
    session_start();
}
```

**cookieToken()** retrieves user_id against the token from the db.
**cookieUserDummy()** retrieves user's email and pass stored against the user_id.
**cookieUserLogin()** starts SESSION for the user.

Comment: The question is: how do you know the original value of the cookie that's been modified? I'd apply a time limit to these cookies - 30 days, 90 days, whatever, and store the expiry date in the database along with the cookie value. Then it's trivial to delete expired ones. You could update the expiry date whenever the cookie is used, but that weakens security.

Comment: as @TangentiallyPerpendicular mentioned, when you save the cookie, store the date/time along with it. Then have a simple query that deletes cookies older than 30 days or whatever. Relogging in every 30 days for example isn't a big hassle.

Comment: When you detect that tge cookie is modified and unset all cookies, then what exactly prevents you from executing a delete sql statement to remove the data from the table?

Comment: Will anyone ever sign in using more than one device? If device A does a remember me, then device B does that, then device A tries to access the site, device B's would be killed off, too, right?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I use GET super-global to get cookie’s value so for example, if a user tries to change some characters of the token, it won’t match with the value in the db. Then it’s gonna expire cookie session.

Comment: @ChrisHaas that’s very interesting take. I haven’t thought about it but I think that won’t be a problem for now, cause a user can have multiple cookie tokens to identify them but killing off previous cookies upon new log in would be problem. So what do you suggest? Let them have multiple tokens for each device?

Comment: @Shadow when I detect a change, cookie is unset and so the session is expired for that user. How would I execute an sql query to delete the cookie from the table if I don’t have any id for that token?

Comment: Do the deletion **before** you unset the cookie.

Comment: Let’s say I’ve got two devices, and I’m given the tokens `aaa` and `bbb`. If I change the latter to `ccc`, you have no way of knowing if it was previously `bbb` or `aaa`, so you can either purge everything for the user, or nothing. I’d pick the latter, and I’d just have an expiration attribute with a cron task to clean things up periodically.

Comment: @Shadow please have a look at the code in the edited question. The deletion does not work because there is no longer a connection to the db.

Comment: There is no code in the question. But more pointedly, just do the deletion before unsetting and closing the db connection?

Comment: @ChrisHaas right, I think the expiration technique is the right option here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user5237857, sounds good. I don't know if you've stumbled upon [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/109439/86698) before, but Scott is a very smart person and respected in the crypto space, and he's got some great ideas for a "remember me" feature in general